# Lentidão na inicialização do console GIT

Tags: git

Boa tarde, estou com problemas ao inicializar meu console do .git. Demora um certo tempo para carrega-lo. Ao digitar qualquer comando demora cerca de 30 s a 1 min. Coisa que até outro dia, ele funcionava normal. Muito rápido em qualquer ação que eu fazia. Já reinstalei o .git. Recomendaram utilizar outros comandos:

```
git config --global user.name "Your Name"
git config --global user.email you@example.com
git commit --amend --reset-author
```

Comment: Tenho esse mesmo problema. Mas só acontece isso comigo, quando utilizo Rwindows. Não sei se é o seu caso.

Comment: Uso windows também, levo minutos pra fazer um commit. =\\

Comment: Faço tudo rapidinho com o Linux, o problema só pode ser o Windows amigo, já utilizei Windows, e demorava minutos também! Veja se isto te ajuda: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4485059/git-bash-is-extremely-slow-in-windows-7-x64

Answer (score 1):

Deduzo que esteja a utilizar a aplicação git desktop para o windows, não a linha de comandos direta como acontece no linux.

A consola git shell que vem com o git desktop para o windows pesa muito mais no computador que o acesso direto via terminal linux. Por isso é que, especialmente se o seu computador não tiver grandes capacidades a nível de hardware, demora bastante a executar simples comandos.

Eu já sofri bastante desse problema, especialmente no meu laptop mais fraco. O que aconselho é executar diretamente o programa Git Shell (Não execute o git shell a partir do git desktop porque é muito mais pesado).